# Deny access to all files not caught by a mod_rewrite rule

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Id like to deny access to everything, except /json-rpc, which should be redirected to /json-rpc.php. My current configuration is:

```
Options -Indexes

Order Deny,Allow 
Deny from All 

<Files "json-rpc"> 
     Order Deny,Allow 
     Allow from All
</Files>

<Files "json-rpc.php"> 
     Order Deny,Allow 
     Allow from All
</Files>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^json-rpc$ json-rpc.php [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

The problem with this is that it allows access to /json-rpc.php directly. How do I make it so that /json-rpc is the ONLY resource available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include this rule inside your `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` block:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} json-rpc\.php
RewriteRule ^ - [L,F]
```

This forbids requests directly for `json-rpc.php`.